# error making twilio rest api call in meteor

Tags: meteor, twilio

I was following the [twilio tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/07/building-a-group-messaging-app-with-meteor-mongodb-and-twilio.html) but was having issues making the http call. I replaced the SID and token with my own, however when I submit the call I receive the following error:

> `Error: failed [401] {"code": 20003, "detail": "Your AccountSid or AuthToken was incorrect.", "message": "Authentication Error - No credentials provided", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20003", "status": 401}(…).`

I am confused because I am providing the correct credentials. My code is below. Thanks!

```
HTTP.call(
            "POST",
            'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/' + 
            'sid' + '/SMS/Messages.json', {
                params: {
                    From: '+14013541756',
                    To: "+14012610096",
                    Body: "yo"
                },
                // Set your credentials as environment variables 
                // so that they are not loaded on the client
                auth:
                    'SID+ ':' +
                    'token'
            },
            // Print error or success to console
            function (error) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('SMS sent successfully.');
                }
            }
        );
  }
```

Comment: Try to log the parameters object and make sure that it is what you expect it to be. BTW, I think that it could be better to use twilio's npm package in your app.

Comment: yeah I was trying to do that, but had errors with meteor. i was able to add     const twilio = Meteor.npmRequire('twilio') in my server. how do I use twilio in the client now?

Comment: I am not sure that I follow. You don't use twilio on the client, only on the server. Did you log the parameters block?

Comment: I want to use functions in twilio in the client but the npm.require is in the server. am I am to just call const twilo in the client? and how would i log the parameters. sorry this is new to me

Comment: Then you should probably familiarize yourself with the language and platform first. You should not call twilio directly from the client (browser), as it is quite obvious you should not expose your credentials to the world. You can create the object that contains your parameters separately, assign it to a variable and log it using `console.log`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't this will even compile:

```
        auth:
            'SID+ ':' +
            'token'
```

Should it be

```
            auth:
                SID+ ':' +
                'token'
```

But that might be a red herring, have you checked your environment variables are set properly, with a console.log(process.env.XXX) - which assumes this method is being called from the server...?

Comment: i didn't use environmental variables I just put the SID and token as strings and i had what you suggested I just mistyped when I took out the actual SID